# Run Length Ecoding

Tags: python

I would like to open an existing file with the following:

```
Hel2o. Th3ese a2re some cha3ra3ct2ers.
Her3e ar2e so5me m2or3e2 ch3aracters.
```

and write this to another file as:

```
Hello. Thhhese aare some chaaaraaactters.
Herrre arre sooooome mmorrree chhharacters.
```

I want to read the string character by character and when an integer *n* is reached to print the previous character *n* amount of times but I'm not sure how to write the code for this. Right now this is what I have:

```
def decode(user_file):
    file1 = open(user_file, 'r')
    file2 = open('test.txt', 'w')
    char = file1.read(1)
    while char:
        file2.write(char)
        char = file1.read(1)
```

This reads the code from the selected file and prints it to the output file, but how do I detect an integer after a character and then print that character *n* times before continuing? I am using python 3.7.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution using regular expressions and [sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('(\w)(\d+)')


def repl(m):
    return m.group(1) * int(m.group(2))


texts = ['Hel2o. Th3ese a2re some cha3ra3ct2ers.', 'Her3e ar2e so5me m2or3e2 ch3aracters.']


for text in texts:
    result = pattern.sub(repl, text)
    print(result)
```

**Output**

```
Hello. Thhhese aare some chaaaraaactters.
Herrre arre sooooome mmorrree chhharacters.
```

**Explanation**

The pattern `(\w)(\d+)` matches a letter followed by a group of 1 or more digits. If the pattern is found it is replaced using the function `repl`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the char in string is a digit or not using regex

```
import re
string2=''
prev_char=''
for i in open(user_file, 'r').read():
    if not re.search('\d',i):
        prev_char=i
        string2+=i
    else:
        string2+=prev_char*int(i)

with open('test.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    file_out.write(string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file content is stored in variable `s`, you can use `str.join` with the following generator expression that pairs the characters by zipping the strings with itself but with one index apart, and tests if the second character of the pair is a digit to repeat the first character that many times:

```
''.join(c * int(n) if n.isdigit() else '' if c.isdigit() else c for c, n in zip(s, s[1:] + '1'))
```

This returns:

```
Hello. Thhhese aare some chaaaraaactters.
Herrre arre sooooome mmorrree chhharacters.
```